# Can I style an element based on its ancestors position property using pure CSS?

Tags: css, css-position

Is it possible to select an element based on its ancestors' CSS property value? Let's say I have following HTML text:

```
<div><!-- ancestor -->
  <!-- I may have N level descendants which are as well ancestors for the upcoming div -->
  <div class="myTarget">
    The div I want to target
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know anything about the ancestors other than if one of them has the CSS property `display: table-cell` then I want `myTarget` to have `position: absolute`, otherwise it should be `position: relative`.

```
.myTarget {
  position: relative;
}

/*************************************************************************************************
 * This is actually the question, how to target .myTarget when some ancestor div contains a given
 * cssProperty. Code below is just pseudo-code not actual CSS.
 *************************************************************************************************/
div[cssProperty=desiredValue] .myTarget {
  position: absolute;
}
```

My guess is that I can't but since it's possible to select elements based on their attributes I thought that perhaps it should be a way to select as well based on its CSS properties.

Comment: I think it would be possible if your CSS would be inline, than `div[style="display: table-cell"]`. Or use JS to check for parent properties

Comment: yes, you can style elements based on ancestor property, its called css attribute styling. Read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Comment: can easily be done if you can add a class to the element that has display: table-cell.

Comment: Is yours a case where you don't control ancestor markup and/or style? Meaning that you don't know where your elements will be inserted? Otherwise, if you know that an element is rendered as a table cell, then you know that. If it changes during document lifetime, you can attach an event handler to detect the change and act upon it by switching your rules for your `myTarget`. I believe we are dealing with a case of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here, to be honest.

Comment: Yes @amn that is the problem: I have no access to the ancestors or their style. This is a reusable component which may appear wherever. I want to avoid JS solutions and try to solve it with pure CSS if possible.

Comment: Short answer -- no it's not possible to select elements based on what styles they or their related elements have, that would introduce another dimension of complexity to CSS. Only through `[style~="display: ..."]` selector, but i wouldn't do that without knowing more about your problem. Long answer: have you read the linked piece on the XY problem, and would you like to edit your answer to elaborate on what kind of component you are developing and why would it ever be so crucially important for it to switch its positioning strategy based on whether it is part of a table cell element or not?

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be a class:

```
<div class="ancestor"> <!-- ancestor -->
  <div class="myTarget">
    The div I want to target
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.myTarget {
  position: relative;
}

div.ancestor > .myTarget {
  position: absolute!important;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option as initially I have no control over my ancestors. Of course I can gain that access with JS but that is exactly what I try to avoid and the reason for me to ask if there is any chance I could achieve my goal with pure CSS.